# $ \ddot{x}_j=F(x_j,\dot{x}_j),\quad x_j(0)=0,\qquad \dot{x}_j(0)=v_j, j=1,2 $

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, analysis

Let $F\in C(\mathbb{R}^n\times\mathbb{R}^n, \mathbb{R}^n), \rho>0$. Given $v_1, v_2\in\left\{v\in\mathbb{R}^n: |v|\leq\rho\right\}, v_1\neq v_2$. Let $x_j$ be the solution of
$$
\ddot{x}_j=F(x_j,\dot{x}_j),\quad x_j(0)=0,\qquad \dot{x}_j(0)=v_j, j=1,2
$$
Prove that there exists $\epsilon>0$ such that $x_1\neq x_2$ on $(0,\epsilon]$.

I don't kwon how to solve the general case so I tried to see the case when $n=1$, but it seems do not show
the general pattern.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need exactly the differential equation for this claim. As $x_j(t)=v_jt+O(t^2)$ you can find some estimate like
$$
\|x_2(t)-x_1(t)\|\ge \|v_2-v_1\|\,|t|-C|t|^2
$$
for small $t$. For sufficiently smaller $t$ the right side is positive, the claim follows.

Comment: I do not see how can show that $x_j(t)=v_j t+O(t^2)$ for we do not know what $F$ is. Could you explain in detail?

Comment: $x_j$ is an at least twice continuously differentiable function. Thus Taylor expansion does apply, for instance in $t=0$ where you know the values of $x_j(0)$ and $x_j'(0)$.

Comment: It seems we can only get $x_j(t)=v_jt+o(t)$. The $F$ and the ODE maybe need to be used sufficiently, but I do not know how to use them.

Comment: $x_j$ is the solution of a second order continuous ODE. It is thus twice differentiable. If you wanted, you could write $x_j(t)=v_jt+\frac12F_jt^2+o(t^2)$, where $F_j=F(0,v_j)$ is the second derivative per ODE.